# Newton method with high multiplicity: rigorous proof

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I am looking for a rigorous yet reasonably short proof of the following statement: let $f\in \mathcal{C}^{m}([a,b])$, and let $\alpha \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
0 = f(\alpha) = f'(\alpha) = f''(\alpha) = \dots = f^{(m-1)}(\alpha), \quad f^{(m)}(\alpha) \neq 0.
$$
Then the Newton method $x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$ converges locally to $\alpha$ linearly with rate $1-\frac{1}{m}$.

The usual way I see this proof is: one writes $f(x) = (x-\alpha)^m g(x)$, where $g(\alpha) \neq 0$, plugs this expression into the iteration function $\Phi(x) = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$, and shows that $\lim_{x\to\alpha} \Phi'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{m}$. Then standard results for fixed-point iterations $x_{k+1} = \Phi(x_k)$ (with a $\mathcal{C}^1$ iteration function $\Phi$) can be used to conclude.

However, on a closer look, I believe this proof has two issues:

1. One needs to use the first and second derivative of $g$ when computing $\Phi'(x)$, so we are silently assuming that $g$ is differentiable in $x=\alpha$.
2. One should also prove that $\Phi'(\alpha)$ actually exists and coincides with the limit, since nothing guarantees that $\Phi$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ function.

I do not see a quick way to fill these holes. Do you know of a way to avoid these two issues? Bonus points if it is a short and natural one, since ideally I'd like to show it in a course for engineering majors.

Comment: So like $f(x)=x^2(1+|x|)$ as example?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, that seems a good example. A quick numerical test confirms that the method does indeed converge linearly with rate 1/2.

Comment: Or to make computations with $g''$ more difficult, use a square root, $f(x)=x^2(1+\sqrt{|x|})$. The expression $x^2g''(x)$ still has limit $0$, but a general treatment would require more careful consideration.

Comment: Exactly! I'd love to see a simple proof that covers these cases and does not assume higher regularity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^{m}([a,b])$ with $m\ge 2$, and let $\alpha \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
0 = f(\alpha) = f'(\alpha) = f''(\alpha) = \dots = f^{(m-1)}(\alpha), \quad f^{(m)}(\alpha) \neq 0.
$$

Repeated application of L'Hôpital's rule gives
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \alpha} \frac{f(x)}{(x-\alpha)^m} 
 &=  \lim_{x \to \alpha} \frac{f'(x)}{m(x-\alpha)^{m-1}} \\
 &=  \lim_{x \to \alpha} \frac{f''(x)}{m(m-1)(x-\alpha)^{m-2}} \\
 &= \cdots \\
 & = \lim_{x \to \alpha} \frac{f^{(m)}(x)}{m!} = \frac{f^{(m)}(\alpha)}{m!} \tag{$*$}
\end{align} 
$$
because the $f^{(m)}$ is continuous at $x=\alpha$, so that the limit in the last line exist. What we need in the following is that the first three limits exist and are equal.

The function
$$
 \Phi(x) = \begin{cases}
 x - f(x)/f'(x) & \text{ if } x \ne \alpha \, ,\\
\alpha & \text{ if } x = \alpha \, ,
\end{cases}
$$
is defined in some neighborhood of $x=\alpha$, and continuously differentiable except possibly at $x=\alpha$.

First we show that $\Phi$ is differentiable at $x = \alpha$ with $\Phi'(\alpha) = 1-1/m$: For $x \ne \alpha$ is
$$
\frac{\Phi(x)-\Phi(\alpha)}{x-\alpha} = 1 - \frac{f(x)}{(x-\alpha)f'(x)} \\
 = 1 - \frac{f(x)}{(x-\alpha)^m} \cdot \left( \frac{f'(x)}{(x-\alpha)^{m-1}}\right)^{-1}
$$
and that converges to $1-\frac 1m$ by $(*)$.

Then we show that $\Phi'$ is continuous at $x=\alpha$: For $x \ne \alpha$ is
$$
 \Phi'(x) = \frac{f(x)f''(x)}{f'(x)^2} = 
\frac{f(x)}{(x-\alpha)^m} \cdot \frac{f''(x)}{(x-\alpha)^{m-2}} \cdot\left( \frac{f'(x)}{(x-\alpha)^{m-1}}\right)^{-2} 
$$
and that converges to $m(m-1) \cdot \frac 1{m^2} = \Phi'(\alpha) $, again by using $(*)$.

Comment: Thanks! This looks good, one last detail though: is the assumption of non-zero denominator for the l'Hopital rule satisfied? Condition 3 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Cases_where_theorem_cannot_be_applied_(Necessity_of_conditions)). In case it doesn't work I think the proof can be fixed by computing separately $\lim f(x) / (x-\alpha)^m$ and $\lim f'(x) / (x-\alpha)^{m-1}$, which are finite.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: $f^{(m)}(\alpha)\ne 0$ implies that all of $f, f', \ldots, f^{(m-1)}$ have an isolated zero at $\alpha$, i.e. there is a neighborhood in which those derivatives are non-zero except at $x=\alpha$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Working with $\lim f(x) / (x-\alpha)^m$ etc as you suggested makes things easier, I have rewritten the proof using that approach.

Comment: Thanks! The proof looks very nice.